# How should I handle NextFC type in next and typescript

Tags: typescript, types, next.js

I can't find `NextFC` type.

I use `{ "next": "9.0.5" }`

NextFC exist in `@types/next`,but NextFC exist in `next/types`.

TypeScript import next/types priority over @types/next.

So,

```
import { NextFC } from 'next';
```

is occurring an error that "NextFC is not undefined in node_modules/next/types"

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@types/next` was deprecated in NextV9.

[reference](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/37299)

So I will use `next/types`.

Ex) `Next.NextFC` →

`NextPage` in `pages/*`

`NextComponentType` in `components/*`